# how to parse an email message and process various information

Tags: c, email-parsing, email-processing

Is there any library to parse email messages? I know there are a lot. 
In addition to basic MIME parsing it should be able to parse things like:

1. If the mail is a forwarded message: parse and tell me the original sender of the message.
2. Get the the parts that should be quoted. I mean like Gmail shows "- Show quoted text -"

It should support one of these: C/C++, PHP, Python

Answer (score 1):

You will, most probably, find some code for it in [Spam Assassin](http://spamassassin.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Here my simple example in PHP:

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents('mime-mixed-related-alternative.eml');

preg_match_all('/((?<=(Content-Type: multipart\/mixed; boundary="))(.*)?(?=(")))|((?<=(Content-Type: multipart\/related; boundary="))(.*)?(?=(")))|((?<=(Content-Type: multipart\/alternative; boundary="))(.*)?(?=(")))/', $str, $boundary);

echo "<pre>";
// print_r($boundary);

$AllPartsUnique = "";
$j=0;

foreach ($boundary[0] as $key => $v) {
  if($key >= 0){
    echo "\n\n\nBoundary " . $v . "\r\n";

    // cut boundary content
    preg_match_all('/(?<=(--'.$v.'))(| |.*|[\s\S]+|\<|\>|\.|\r|\n|\0|@|\w+)?(?=(--'.$v.'--))/', $str, $part);

    $bname = $v;

    foreach ($part[0] as $v) {
        // echo "PART " . $bname . " " . $v . "\r\n";
        $parts = explode("--".$bname, $v);

        echo "<pre>";
        foreach ($parts as $v) {
            // echo "\r\nSINGLE PART " . $v . "\r\n";     
            // $AllPartsUnique[$j] = $v;
            // with html visible on page
            $AllPartsUnique[$j] = htmlentities($v);     
            $j++;  
        }
    }
  }
}
echo "<pre>";
// print_r($AllPartsUnique);



foreach($AllPartsUnique as $key => $one) {
  foreach ($boundary[0] as $find) {
    if(strpos($one, $find) !== false){
        unset($AllPartsUnique[$key]); 
    }
  }    
}

echo "<pre>";
 print_r($AllPartsUnique);
preg_match_all('/(?<=((\n)To: )|(^To: ))(.*)+?(?=())/', $str, $to);
echo "To " . $to[0][0];

preg_match_all('/(?<=((\n)From: )|(^From: ))(.*)+?(?=())/', $str, $from);
echo "From " . $from[0][0];

preg_match_all('/(?<=((\n)Subject: )|(^Subject: ))(.*)+?(?=())/', $str,  $subject);
echo "Subject " . $subject[0][0];

// end script 
die();
?>
```

Amd here mime message example:

```
From: ddd@email.coc
To: to@email.coc
Subject: Example Email
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="MixedBoundaryString"

--MixedBoundaryString
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="RelatedBoundaryString"

--RelatedBoundaryString
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="AlternativeBoundaryString"

--AlternativeBoundaryString
Content-Type: text/plain;charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

This is the plain text part of the email.

--AlternativeBoundaryString
Content-Type: text/html;charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
  <body>=0D
    <img src=3D=22cid:masthead.png=40email.coc=22 width 800 height=3D80=
 =5C>=0D
    <p>This is the html part of the email.</p>=0D
    <img src=3D=22cid:logo.png=40email.coc=22 width 200 height=3D60 =5C=
>=0D
  </body>=0D
</html>=0D

--AlternativeBoundaryString--

--RelatedBoundaryString
Content-Type: image/jpgeg;name="logo.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline;filename="logo.png"
Content-ID: <logo.png@email.coc>

amtsb2hiaXVvbHJueXZzNXQ2XHVmdGd5d2VoYmFmaGpremxidTh2b2hydHVqd255aHVpbnRyZnhu
dWkgb2l1b3NydGhpdXRvZ2hqdWlyb2h5dWd0aXJlaHN1aWhndXNpaHhidnVqZmtkeG5qaG5iZ3Vy
a25qbW9nNXRwbF0nemVycHpvemlnc3k5aDZqcm9wdHo7amlodDhpOTA4N3U5Nnkwb2tqMm9sd3An
LGZ2cDBbZWRzcm85eWo1Zmtsc2xrZ3g=

--RelatedBoundaryString
Content-Type: image/jpgeg;name="masthead.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline;filename="masthead.png"
Content-ID: <masthead.png@email.coc>

aXR4ZGh5Yjd1OHk3MzQ4eXFndzhpYW9wO2tibHB6c2tqOTgwNXE0aW9qYWJ6aXBqOTBpcjl2MC1t
dGlmOTA0cW05dGkwbWk0OXQwYVttaXZvcnBhXGtsbGo7emt2c2pkZnI7Z2lwb2F1amdpNTh1NDlh
eXN6dWdoeXhiNzhuZzdnaHQ3eW9zemlqb2FqZWt0cmZ1eXZnamhka3JmdDg3aXV2dWd5aGVidXdz
dhyuhehe76YTGSFGA=

--RelatedBoundaryString--

--MixedBoundaryString
Content-Type: application/pdf;name="Invoice_1.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Invoice_1.pdf"

aGZqZGtsZ3poZHVpeWZoemd2dXNoamRibngganZodWpyYWRuIHVqO0hmSjtyRVVPIEZSO05SVURF
SEx1aWhudWpoZ3h1XGh1c2loZWRma25kamlsXHpodXZpZmhkcnVsaGpnZmtsaGVqZ2xod2plZmdq
a2psajY1ZWxqanNveHV5ZXJ3NTQzYXRnZnJhZXdhcmV0eXRia2xhanNueXVpNjRvNWllc3l1c2lw
dWg4NTA0

--MixedBoundaryString
Content-Type: application/pdf;name="SpecialOffer.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="SpecialOffer.pdf"

aXBvY21odWl0dnI1dWk4OXdzNHU5NTgwcDN3YTt1OTQwc3U4NTk1dTg0dTV5OGlncHE1dW4zOTgw
cS0zNHU4NTk0eWI4OTcwdjg5MHE4cHV0O3BvYTt6dWI7dWlvenZ1em9pdW51dDlvdTg5YnE4N3Z3
OTViOHk5cDV3dTh5bnB3dWZ2OHQ5dTh2cHVpO2p2Ymd1eTg5MGg3ajY4bjZ2ODl1ZGlvcjQ1amts
dfnhgjdfihn=

--MixedBoundaryString--
```